# Obtain Bootstrap Results in Matrix

Tags: r, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have written the following code.

```
library(quantreg)

# return the g function:
G = function(m, N, gamma) {
  Tm = m * N
  k = 1:Tm
  Gvalue = sqrt(m) * (1 + k/m) * (k/(m + k))^gamma
  return(Gvalue)
}



sqroot <- function(A) {
  e = eigen(A)
  v = e$vectors
  val = e$values
  sq = v %*% diag(sqrt(val)) %*% solve(v)
  return(t(sq))
}

fa = function(m, N, a) {
  Tm = m * N
  k = 1:Tm
  t = (m + k)/m
  f_value = (t - 1) * t * (a^2 + log(t/(t - 1)))
  return(sqrt(f_value))
}

m = 50
N = 2
n= 50*3
x1 = matrix(runif(n, 0, 1), ncol = 1)
x = cbind(1, x1)
beta = c(1, 1)
xb = x %*% beta
pr = 1/(1+exp(-xb))  
y = rbinom(n,1,pr)

# calculate statistic:
stat = function(y, x, m, N, a) {
  y_train = y[1:m]
  x_train = x[(1:m),]
  y_test = y[-(1:m)]
  x_test = x[-(1:m),]
  
  fit = glm(y ~ 0 + x, family="binomial")
  coef = coef(fit)
  log_predict = predict(fit, type="response")
  sigma = sqrt(1/(m-1)* sum((y_train - log_predict)^2))
  
  Jvalue = t(x_train) %*% x_train/m * sigma^2
  Jsroot = sqroot(Jvalue)
  
  fvalue = fa(m, N, a)
  score1 = apply((x_test * as.vector((y_test - x_test  %*% coef))), 2, cumsum)
  statvalue1 = t(solve(Jsroot) %*% t(score1))/fvalue/sqrt(m)
  statmax1 = pmax(abs(statvalue1[, 1]), abs(statvalue1[, 2]))
  
  result = list(stat = statmax1)
  return(result)
}
m =50
N = 2
a = 2.795
value = stat(y, x, m, N, a)
value
```

I want to perform bootstrap to obtain B = 999 number of statistics. I use the following r code. But it produces an error saying "Error in statistic(data, original, ...) :
argument "m" is missing, with no default"

```
library(boot)
data1 = data.frame(y = y, x = x1, m = m , N = N, a = a)
head(data1)
boot_value = boot(data1, statistic = stat, R = 999)
```

Can anyone give me a hint? Also, am I able to get the bootstrap results in a matrix format? Since the `stat function` gives `100` values.

Comment: From `?boot::boot` "*The first argument passed will always be the original data. The second will be a vector of indices*" which is not how your function is set up -- from a quick glance I can't really see how you are doing the sampling

Comment: @user20650 Thank you!. I got your point. Actually, I want to resample the data first (B = 1000 times) and then compute the statistics for B number of times using the ``stat`` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different kinds of bootstrapping. If you want to draw from your data `999` samples with replications of same size of your data you may just use `replicate`, no need for packages.

We put the data to be resampled into a data frame. It looks to me like `m, N, a` remain constant, so we just provide it as vectors.

```
data2 <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)
```

`stat` function needs to be adapted to unpack `y` and `x`-matrix. At the bottom we remove the `list` call to get just a vector back. `unname`ing will just give us the numbers.

```
stat2 <- function(data, m, N, a) {
  y_train <- data[1:m, 1]
  x_train <- as.matrix(data[1:m, 2:3])
  y_test <- data[-(1:m), 1]
  x_test <- as.matrix(data[-(1:m), 2:3])
  y <- data[, "y"]
  x <- as.matrix(data[, 2:3])
  fit <- glm(y ~ 0 + x, family="binomial")
  coef <- coef(fit)
  log_predict <- predict(fit, type="response")
  sigma <- sqrt(1/(m-1) * sum((y_train - log_predict)^2))
  Jvalue <- t(x_train) %*% x_train/m * sigma^2
  Jsroot <- sqroot(Jvalue)
  fvalue <- fa(m, N, a)
  score1 <- apply((x_test * as.vector((y_test - x_test %*% coef))), 2, cumsum)
  statvalue1 <- t(solve(Jsroot) %*% t(score1))/fvalue/sqrt(m)
  statmax1 <- pmax(abs(statvalue1[, 1]), abs(statvalue1[, 2]))
  result <- unname(statmax1)
  return(result)
}
```

`replicate` is a cousin of `sapply`, designed for repeated evaluation. In the call we just `sample` the rows `999` times and already get a matrix back. As in `sapply` we need to `t`ransform our result.

```
res <- t(replicate(999, stat2(data2[sample(1:nrow(data2), nrow(data2), replace=TRUE), ], m, N, a)))
```

#### Result

As result we get `999` bootstrap replications in the rows with `100` attributes in the columns.

```
str(res)
# num [1:999, 1:100] 0.00205 0.38486 0.10146 0.12726 0.47056 ...
```

The code also runs quite fast.

```
user  system elapsed 
3.46    0.01    3.49
```

**Note**, that there are different kinds of bootstrapping. E.g. sometimes just a part of the sample is resampled, weights are used, clustering is applied etc. Since you attempted to use `boot` the method shown should be the default, though.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to do moving block bootstrap to see any differences in estimates. I wrote this code ``N = 150
``data.bt = matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol = 100) ``  # local vector for a bootstrap replication

Comment: ``k <- 6                                  # size blocks
nrep <- 100                             # replications
for(irep in 1:nrep) {                   # loop
  for(i in 1:ceiling(N/k)) {            # random blocks
    endpoint <- sample(k:N, size=1)     # ndomly sampling endpoints
    data.bt[(i-1)*k+1:k] <- data2[endpoint-(k:1)+1] # copying blocks
  }
  data.bt <- data.bt[1:N]           # trim overflow when k doesn't divide N
  stat.bt[irep] <- stat2(data.bt[-1] , m, N, a)
  if(irep%%10==0) print(irep)        
}
``My question is how to input the data? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @score324 Interesting. I'd put into a `t(replicate(100, ...))` a more vectorized code: `data.bt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ceiling(N/k), function(x) {endpoint <- sample(k:N, size=1);data2[endpoint-(k:1)+1, ]}));stat2(data.bt, m, N, a)`. However, as you see, `stat2` seems to need to be adapted somehow.

Comment: @score324 Happy to hear that!